# How to get POST request values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So we have several domains that have a form to send a FORM POST Request to a single domain. We essentially collect addresses and respond with products. Currently we are doing this with just plain PHP, Jquery, XML, lots of stuff going on there. But I'm wanting to rebuild some of this in react. After building a simple template that looks great it seems I can't solve a seemingly simple issue. How to send this post request data into my react app. Every time I search google for this I see examples of people doing AJAX request to get external data. I just want the post data sent to my react App. I know react is client side and not server side like php, but is there a way to collect the POST data that is sent into my application when it is initialized? Or at least carry over a sessionID into my application. I was thinking of using a cookie or localstorage, but those seem to be for a single domain. Any help or pointing in the right direction will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What you want goes against the philosophy of Single Page Applications and react in general. Use jwt for example to achieve that, there are many examples of this

Comment: Are you using all those other websites on a single domain or they are part of your sub domain.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your problem is that you want to send your form post data into your react app during react app initialization. If I am right that this is your problem then you can do one thing. 
You can send your form data in query params after filling the form and the data which is stored in query params of your link can be stored using react in `componentWillMount` method by resolving the data of query params. and after that if you want to have a clean url you can redirect the user to clean url after storing that query params data in some storage of browser.

Comment: I did this, but I also base64 encoded my params before sending and decoded it after. I did this a while back, but thought I'd mention it for others. Thanks!